# Ionic App AJAX POST Request returns 405

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I'm building an app in Ionic and I'm having a problem that's holding me up.

This AJAX post method always returns the `405 error`, despite it's working on my AngularJS website with the exact same code. 
My NodeJS server on Heroku has CORS allowances for all CRUD actions. In addition, I'm testing this application on my phone, not "ionic serve".

```
$scope.doLogin = function() {
var data = {
  email: 'cat@cat.com',
  password: 'cat'
};

console.log(data);

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/login',
  data: data,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.success( function (newData) {
  console.log(newData)
  $scope.modal.hide()
});
};
```

I added

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain=true
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']
```

in my route provider but it hasn't solved the problem.

The strange thing is that a GET request works perfectly.

Thank you!